# jQuery detect a <input> is focus when blur from another <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two input elements on my page and I want to detect when
 `#aa blur`, is `#bb focused`?

---

Here is what I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="aa" name="aa">
<input type="text" id="bb" name="bb">
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#aa').blur(function () {
    console.log($('#bb').is(':focus'));
});
```

---

Although it works in theory,the output always returns `false`.

I know this is because #aa's blur event always happen before #bb's focus event.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you want #bb to be focused? Or just to know if they tabbed over to #bb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use setTimeout() with 0 as offset to delay the call to the next cycle.

```js
$('#aa').blur(function () {
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log($('#bb').is(':focus'));
    },0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="aa" name="aa">
<input type="text" id="bb" name="bb">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a global variable, updating its value when `blur` occurs on `#aa`, and then using it in `focus` event of `#bb` :

```
var i = 0;

$('#aa').blur(function () {
   i=1;
});

$('input:text').not('#aa').blur(function () {//reset when other textboxes are blurred
   i=0;
});

$('#bb').focus(function () {
   if(i==1){
       //it worked!
   }
});
```

Comment: But with this way, it will be triggered whenever "bb" is focused, even if "aa" was blurred long ago

Comment: @HéctorE Nice catch! I guess the update will fix this.

Comment: I was trying it right now, it's better but still it only works with inputs. It should be able to catch every other focusing... Is there any selector that selects everything?

Comment: @HéctorE `$('*')` maybe? :)

Comment: I'm trying it but it doesn't seem to work properly... I think it is because the blur can not be applied to elements like the background, then the function doesn't trigger